# Error on flutter iOS :Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAggregateQuery'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i have been having problem on iOS after i add `$FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0'` in my podfile because i have issues installing after updating firebase packages to the latest version i keep having this issue after overriding it to `9.6.0`

here is the error

```
Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRAggregateQuery'
/Users/technology/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.3.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:587:2


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'aggregateQuery'
/Users/technology/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.3.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:587:21


ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No visible @interface for 'FIRQuery' declares the selector 'count'
/Users/technology/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.3.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:587:45


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'aggregateQuery'
/Users/technology/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.3.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:589:3
```

here is my pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0'

platform :ios, '15.0'
# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I have the same problem